# S3 URL and Acumatica FileID value

Tags: acumatica

We currently have External file storage enabled to have our files stored in s3. However, I know that these resources are still served over the acumatica instance url and go through the Acumatica security. However, we have a need to link to some of these resources directly from remote/3rd party systems. My plan is to have a direct s3 url/link to the resource, however, Acumatica stores the file as some sort of random object id. My question is if anyone knows where this fileID (Example below) comes from. We have looked in several tables that seem to have some relationship to uploaded files, but can't find anything that resembles this.

Any ideas?

/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=40ff3dbd-ee7f-4af8-b1cc-7e6b96183fec

Comment: UPDATE: in case anyone else has the same question...I figured out that the UploadFileRevision table has a field called BlobHandler that stores the name that is used as the object id in s3. But need to keep in mind that even though the db stores the value in all uppercase, it's actually stored in s3 as all lowercase.

Comment: Is there any other information you're still looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Actually, i do have a question...does Acumatica use the aws SDK to manage the storage? or is it done through the rest apis? If the former, are we able to rely on this sdk for other needs we have as opposed to interacting with aws/s3 over the https post/rest api? Any information you can provide would be most appreciated. Thank you. @HB_ACUMATICA

Comment: It uses AWS SDK, you will find the library of the same name deployed in the Bin folder of Acumatica IIS Virtual Directory. You might be able to re-purpose the PX.Data.Update.Storage.AmazonS3Storage class. PX.Data.Update.Storage.PXStorageHelper is the wrapper that sits on top of it.

Comment: I don't think there are restrictions to using AWS SDK directly either.

Comment: Final Update: thank you for the direction. We were able to use the AWS SDK directly to handle the need.

Answer (score 0):

There are two keys required to identify a file in Acumatica:

```
FileID: a Guid that uniquely identifies one or multiple revision of a file
FileRevisionID: an Integer value that identifies a specific revision of a file
```

The first key FileID can be found in the `UploadFile` table. With that key you can get metadata that applies for all revisions of the file like filename:

[image]

UploadFile table doesn't contain the file data. File content will be in UploadFileRevision table or is setup to be hosted by an external provider. To get the Base64 file content from database you need to provide FileID as well as the FileRevisionID and fetch the Data blob from UploadFileRevision:

[image]

Linking document to File is done with the NoteID field. Documents like SOOrder contains a NoteID field that identifies the SOOrder. When you add a file to that Sales Order document, an entry is created in the `NoteDoc` table which links the NoteID to multiple FileID (attached to document).

Here's an example how to get the 2 FileIDs associated with a Sales Order:
[image]

First use the Sales Order Nbr. key to locate the NoteID:
[image]

Then search FileID in the NoteDoc table with the NoteID of the Sales Order:
[image]